# Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@2x.png) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:

Tags: php, javascript, html

WideImage::load($category)->resize(29, 28) not work with links that contents @2x ...I get this error

**Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@2x.png) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:**

Example

```
 http://myurl/icon_filter04@2x.png
```

when I use a link without @2x, it works great

Here is my code:

```
WideImage::load($category)->resize(29, 28)->saveToFile('img/category/'.$temp_name_category.'');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always `urlencode` your path when you have those symbols in it:

```
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]
```

Try:  `http://myurl/icon_filter04%402x.png`

Comment: PHP has a built-in function for this; you should never have to do any kind of escaping manually.

Comment: I have already tried use urlencode function but it doesn't work. I'm getting the same error

Comment: @shadsauhduisad - what happens if you put the urlencoded URL into your browser address field? Can you access it from there?

Comment: and if is the link https? Have any problem?

Comment: Now i'm getting  "Unable to find the wrapper "https" "

Answer (score 1):

The `@` symbol is a reserved character in a URL.

If you have a URL containing an `@` symbol, you must escape it.

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode your URLs safely.

```
$safeFilename = "http://murl/".urlencode("icon_filter04@2x.png");
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the @ , so `http://myurl/icon_filter04%402x.png`